# About the concurrency of Docker

Tags: nginx, docker

I am running my containers with "--net=host" to make sure all the networking kernel setting be the same.

But,when the concurrency of request getting bigger.
It shows "1024 worker connections not enough" in the Nginx error log
But when we don't use container, it runs perfectly.
The setting of nginx and php-fpm is all the same.

By the way,
I used "ab" to test containers.
And it shows "apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)"